# How to fix compile libpq-fe.h in cmake error in C++

Tags: postgresql, gcc, cmake, c++17, clion

With g++ I compile my program "g++ main.cpp -lpq" without error,
and with cmake on Clion this error appears

i using #include <'postgresql/libpq-fe.h'>

```
>/opt/clion-2018.3.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/cmake-build-debug --target PGsql -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable PGsql
CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/main.cpp.o : Dans la fonction « CloseConn(pg_conn*) » :
/home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/main.cpp:9 : référence indéfinie vers « PQfinish »
CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/main.cpp.o : Dans la fonction « ConnectDB() » :
/home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/main.cpp:19 : référence indéfinie vers « PQconnectdb »
/home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/main.cpp:22 : référence indéfinie vers « PQstatus »
CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/main.cpp.o : Dans la fonction « CreateEmployeeTable(pg_conn*) » :
/home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/main.cpp:175 : référence indéfinie vers « PQresultStatus »
/home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/main.cpp:178 : référence indéfinie vers « PQclear »
/home/dev/Bureau/ENEDIS/PGsql/main.cpp:185 : référence indéfinie vers « PQclear »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'PGsql' failed
make[3]: *** [PGsql] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PGsql.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'PGsql' failed
make: *** [PGsql] Error 2
```

My CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(PGsql)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(PGsql main.cpp)
```

I guess a configuration is missing in CMAKE but I do not know what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't make CMake pass `-lpq`. Use `target_link_libraries()` for that:

```
target_link_libraries(PGsql pq)
```

Note that to make your program portable, you first need to find libraries and includes you are going to use. See `find_package()`, `find_library()` and `find_path()` commands.

You could've also bothered translating error messages to English.